# Applet Class Name - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception, classname

I am trying to upload an applet onto a website and it's asking me class name. I've used RoskieApplet.class/roskieapplet.class and RoskiePanel.class/roskiepanel.class but it's giving me a ClassNotFoundException on the website when I try to run it. I can run the applet locally on my computer without any issues.

```
    public class RoskieApplet extends Applet
    {
        static int xCord;
        static int yCord;
        static int score = 0;
        static int time = 10000;

        public void init()
        {
            add(new RoskiePanel());
            setSize(875, 800);
        }

        public class RoskiePanel extends JPanel
        {
             //Should I post everything in here?
        }
    }
```

I have searched for a similar problem on StackOverflow but have not encountered any solutions. This is my first post so I apologize if I have any beginner mistakes. Please let me know if there's any information I can add. Thanks!

Edit: I only uploaded the .java file on to the website.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a package declaration at the top of the class? If so, you need to include that, for example: `your.package.RoskieApplet`

You will need to create a JAR file that includes all of the classes and resources needed to run your Applet. See these links for more information:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/runAppletFunction.html

Comment: I skipped the .class but it's still giving me the same error. I did not declare a package at the top of my class, should I?
I just added that I only uploaded the .java file onto the webiste.

Comment: No, that's not required but the website would probably be confused if you had one. Which site are you using?